# How to get text I inputted into textView

Tags: ios, uitextview

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
    self.textView.text=textView.text;
    self.statusString=textView.text;
}
```

In this method ,it returns self.statusString nil or empty description(when initialized statusString it happens), and `self.textView.text` is nil too.

How to get the text I inputted into textView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the different name to the connected textView .

```
IBOutlet UITextView *objTextVIew ;
```

**In ViewDidLoad**

```
 objTextVIew.delegate = self
    -(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
        self.objTextVIew.text=textView.text; // also see that have  you got textView's text
        self.statusString=textView.text;
    }
```

Comment: I forgotten to 'set self.textView=textView;'......just create textView and add it into view. sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

At first check whether your textView outlet is ok or not.

You don't have to write so much code to get textView's text. I just wrote this code and it's working fine.

```
- (IBAction)sendDataToFirstVC:(id)sender {

    self.firstLabel.text = self.textView.text;
}
```

[image]